# How do I change color to a tab menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
let menuOpen = false;
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    menu.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menu.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* Cornice */
.menu2 {

  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */

 
}
/* Interno */
.menu1 {
  font-size:55px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;

}
.tab {
  color: transparent;
  left: 30%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 
}


a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  
}

/* animazione */

.menu.open .menu1 {
  font-size:35px;
  color: red;
  transform: translateX(-180px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu.open a {
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
  <title>   
    bEt4
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <video src="video1.webm" autoplay loop playsinline muted></video>
 <div class="menu2">
 <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu1">  
    <h1 style=" font-family:Consolas;">bEt4</h1> 
    </div>
  </div>
<ul class="tab" style="left: 100px; top: 150px;;">
  <li><a href="#" data-text="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="archives">archives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="tags">tags</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="categories">categories</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="about">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the menu1 name (bEt4), the element moves, linked to this action I need to make the 'a' element change color from transparent to red. I think it is the .menu.open a part that is not working but maybe I need to add some js or a different css line. If someone knows how to solve it, it would help me a lot. Thanks in advance to anyone that tries to help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your "a" elements are not changing because in your css you are applying changes to ".menu.open a " but your  tag is outside the .menu div and is enclosed in .menu2 div so if you change your css from ".menu.open a" to ".menu2.open a" it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing in your css '.menu.open a' to '.menu2.open a'
and adding menu2 in your js code

I hope it works for ya :D

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menu2 = document.querySelector('.menu2');
let menuOpen = false;
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    menu.classList.add('open');
    menu2.classList.add('open')
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menu.classList.remove('open');
    menu2.classList.remove('open')
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* Cornice */
.menu2 {

  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */

 
}
/* Interno */
.menu1 {
  font-size:55px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;

}
.tab {
  color: transparent;
  left: 30%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 
}


a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  
}

/* animazione */

.menu.open .menu1 {
  font-size:35px;
  color: red;
  transform: translateX(-180px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu2.open a {
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
  <title>   
    bEt4
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <video src="video1.webm" autoplay loop playsinline muted></video>
 <div class="menu2">
 <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu1">  
    <h1 style=" font-family:Consolas;">bEt4</h1> 
    </div>
  </div>
<ul class="tab" style="left: 100px; top: 150px;;">
  <li><a href="#" data-text="home">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="archives">archives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="tags">tags</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="categories">categories</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="about">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```